# How do you install a .NET 6 Windows Service (Worker Service) using a Visual Studio Installer project?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows-installer, .net-6.0

I Have a Worker Service written in c# that needs to be installed as a Windows Service (configured by calling the `UseWindowsService` method).

[This guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022) specifies how to create an installer for a .NET 6 application, but this installer only copies the app's files.

How can I install the service contained in the executable?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [sc create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create) command in order to register service. Like this:

```
sc.exe create NewService binpath= c:\windows\system32\NewServ.exe
```

P.S. pay attention, there is mandatory space after `binpath=`

Comment: either for delete or create it is worked like charm you are great

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot more steps to make it a service you can create.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service

I was missing some of the nuget packages and other hand edits to the csproj file.